# RefreshEnv equivalent for MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to refresh environment variables in Mac without exiting the terminal. Precisely, something like 'refreshenv' which we use in 'cmder' in windows?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "refresh"? `source .profile`?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [doing "`source .cshrc ; source .login`" (for csh or tcsh) or "`source .bashrc"`](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aeee) (if you've created one in bash), macOS's Terminal.app also has "Reset" and "Hard Reset" available under the "Shell" menu